# Datagridview row Index was out of range in vb

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Hi  I want to loop my data grid view on tick event. This code do the loop however at the end of the loop, it prompt error

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size
>   of the collection."

at the commented line in the code below.

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
   'loop each rows in datagridview
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To DataGridView2.RowCount - 1
        If DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(17).Value Then  'error prompted
        'delete 1 row from datagridview
    Else
        'do some other operations
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

this error happen when `DataGridView2.RowCount = 1`.
how to solve this? should i add this line before the for loop? i'm newbie, please advise.

```
If DataGridView2.RowCount <> 1 Then
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are deleting rows you MUST use a `Step -1` [For loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) because rows number change if you delete one of them.

In your code:

```
For i = DataGridView2.RowCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
```

Comment: so should i eliminate the Dim i As Integer = 0?

Comment: Not necessarily. You have to change the sintax of For loop so i started as DataGridView rows number. You can also use this syntax: For i as Integer = DataGridView2.RowCount - 1 To 0 Step -1